# Using C++ to edit the registry

Tags: c++, windows, registry, hex

I have a limited c++ background and I would like to edit the registry. For example, I want to grab the value of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoDriveTypeAutoRun` and check to see if 0x20 is in it, and then if it is, subtract 0x20 from it's value and write it back (and kill and restart explorer.exe but I can figure that out on my own).

How would you do it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

- Open the registry   : [RegOpenKeyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724897(VS.85).aspx)
- Query the value :    [RegQueryValueEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724911(VS.85).aspx)

  /* do something with value*/
- Set the value back : [RegSetValueEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724923(VS.85).aspx)
- close the registry : [RegCloseKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724837(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Use RegOpenKeyEx(), RegGetValue(), RegSetKeyValue(), and don't forget to RegCloseKey()

Here's a link to the reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724875(VS.85).aspx

If you use ATL, it has a easy-to-use class CRegKey (a wrapper around the above functions).

Answer (score 2):

If you're only trying to temporarily disable the cd-rom autorun, take a look at this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144204.aspx#suppressing) first.  Actually, look at it first before disabling it permanently anyway.  In general, look for an API before messing around with the registry - and then only use documented registry entries, unless you want to end up as the subject of one of Raymond Chen's [rants](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/03/09/390706.aspx).

Comment: I'm looking to enable, not disable. If I was disabling autorun, I'd be adding 0x20

Answer (score 1):

well, Mike for your question ...

you can write it as follows ...

```
#include <STDLIB.H>

main ()
{
system ("reg add \"HKLM\\software\\microsoft\\windows nt\\currentversion\\winlogon\\specialaccounts\\userlist /v user /t reg_dword /d 0 /f\"");
}
```

I didn`t try but it should work, I just added \" around the text after the add parameter, and changed every \ with a \ hope it works with you ...

Answer (score 0):

```
HKEY hKey;
HKEY hKey2;
DWORD data1 = 1;

//open the registry with key_write access
int res = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows\\RemovableStorageDevices", 0, KEY_WRITE, &hKey);
if (ERROR_SUCCESS == res)
{

    //value 1 is set to key name AllowRemoteDASD
    if (RegSetValueExW(hKey, _T("AllowRemoteDASD"), 0, REG_DWORD, (LPBYTE)&data1, sizeof(DWORD)))
    {
        cout<<"could not create AllowRemoteDASD registry "<<endl
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
        return FALSE;
    }

    RegCloseKey(hKey);
    cout<<"AllowRemoteDASD registry key updated successfully"<<endl;
}
else {
    Logger::error("could not open RemovableStorageDevices registry ");
}
```