# How do I assign an icon to a custom file type?

Tags: windows, icons, file-type

Is there any way to do so in C or C++ (I know that it can be done in C#, so if you know how to, it'd also help!)?

What I want is a way to, automatically and through my own application, associate a custom file extension with a custom icon. For example, something that would make all current and subsequent .foo files have an image of their own, instead of the bland white paper sheet default. Just like what Java does to .jar files and Dev-C++ to .c and .cpp upon them being installed.

Through my researches I've found a lot of related information about a thing called Shell or something. I wound up myself at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127427%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and as viable what it says may seem, I have no idea on how to implement it at all, nor grasp what exactly it is about. Sorry if I sound noobish!

OS is Windows.

Comment: this has nothing to do with the language, it's specific to the shell/OS you are using (i.e. the technique for achieving this will vary from Windows to Linux/Gnome, Linux/KDE, Mac OS X etc).

Comment: The page you linked to is talking about the *registry*. Which is the place Windows stores file associations (as well as a whole lot of other stuff). Suggest you google about how the registry works, and how to modify it in code.

Comment: is your program a win32 based app?

Comment: The link is correct.  An installer writes those registry keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to know how to modify registry in c++, here is a post that explains that:

[Registry and c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863991/using-c-to-edit-the-registry)

In the link you provided you have the keys that you need to update

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/[yourextension]

the call to SHChangeNotify is only needed to tell explorer to refresh once you modified the icon.