# Make new filetype use custom icon

Tags: c++, windows, explorer

I am designing a new programming language, and I want to allow my users to embed a custom icon in the output binary file, which is not a standard EXE file.

EXE files allow custom icons (not all .EXE files use the same icon). How can I do that with my own binary files?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to provide different icons for files with the same extension, you need to register an Icon Handler shell extension. For details, see [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144122.aspx) in MSDN.

Your handler will need to know how to extract the icon from the file and return it to Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

These instructions should help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127427%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Essentially, create the registry key in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT for your extension (follow other examples, or that link) to specify an icon, and call `SHChangeNotify()` with `SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED`.

This answer covers registry changes in C++:

[Using C++ to edit the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863991/using-c-to-edit-the-registry)