# Editing windows xp Registry with Scripting

Tags: c#, c++, registry, windows-xp

I want to write a script to access the registry key , and then create a new value and give it a data and then reboot .
My questions is :
1) I will use notepad to write the program , so which programming language is most suitable :  c/c++ or c# ?

2) Where can i find a sample program that do what i want , or where can i find a tutorial to learn how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Choosing the right language depends on your project. If you're willing to use .Net framework, registry operations would be much easier, but of course, C++ has its own benefits.
In C#, you could use `Registry.GetValue` and `Registry.SetValue` (should add using `Microsoft.Win32`) See the links below:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Win32.Registry.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h5e7chcf.aspx

In C++, It's a little more complicated. See this post: [Using C++ to edit the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863991/using-c-to-edit-the-registry)

Answer (score 0):

1: cmd/JavaScript/VBScript are generally more suitable for administration tasks and don't require any additional software on WinXP. C# may be suitable if you are guaranteed to have .Net on the box, C++ definitely requires non-trivial amount of tools to be installed to build and run your code.

2: internet.