# C++ does not alter registry even though running without errors

Tags: c++, windows, registry, mingw

Trying to write code to change the registry keys with c++ after endless amount of time I reached this point but this code still does not edit the registry even when running as admin

to change the registry 4 functions are needed according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863991/using-c-to-edit-the-registry) question which I used and every single one of them returns a zero which means that the function completed without errors but still no values are changed in the registry gui

the `SecurityHealth` strartup service is running on my machine and has the path `%windir%\system32\SecurityHealthSystray.exe` and type `REG_EXPAND_SZ`

I even tried creating a new entry similar to the  `SecurityHealth` and still nothing is changed

I am compiling as admin and running as admin

```
HKEY open_reg()
{
    int result;
    LPCSTR lpSubKey = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run";
    HKEY hKey; 

    result = RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, lpSubKey, 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE|KEY_WRITE|KEY_READ|KEY_SET_VALUE, &hKey);

    if ( result != 0)
    {
        cout << " Failed to open registry. - [ "<< result<< "]" <<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Found registry key. - [" << result<<"]" << endl;
    }
    return hKey;
}




HKEY find_reg_value(HKEY handle)
{
    

    LPCSTR lpValueName = "SecurityHealth";
    DWORD BufferSize = TOTALBYTES;
    DWORD cbData;
    int dwRet;

    PPERF_DATA_BLOCK PerfData = (PPERF_DATA_BLOCK) malloc( BufferSize );
    cbData = BufferSize;

    cout << "\nRetrieving the data..." << endl;

    dwRet = RegQueryValueExA( handle,
                             lpValueName,
                             NULL,
                             NULL,
                             (LPBYTE) PerfData,
                             &cbData );

    if ( dwRet == 0 ) 
    { 
        cout << "Successfully quered [" << dwRet << "]"<<endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Failed to query  Error code : [" << dwRet << "]"<<endl;
    } 

    return handle;
}






void set_reg_value(HKEY handle)
{
    
    int result;
    LPCSTR lpValueName = "SecurityHealth";
    std::string file = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
    
    const  char * sth = file.c_str();
    unsigned char m_Test[file.size()];
    strcpy((char*)m_Test, sth);

    DWORD DATA_SIZE = file.size()+1;

    result = RegSetValueExA(handle,lpValueName,0,REG_EXPAND_SZ,m_Test,DATA_SIZE);
    
    if ( result == 0 ) 
    { 
        cout << "Successfully changed value [" << result << "]"<<endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Failed to change value  Error code : [" << result << "]"<<endl;
    } 
    RegCloseKey (handle);
}


int main()
{
    cout << "testing windows registry " << endl;
    HKEY reg_handle = open_reg();
    HKEY handler = find_reg_value(reg_handle);
    set_reg_value(handler);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;   
}
```

the compiled exe output in the terminal

```
testing windows registry
Found registry key. - [0]

Retrieving the data...
Successfully quered [0]
Successfully changed value [0]
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Compiled with `g++ regutil.cpp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you are compiling as a 32-bit program but looking at a 64-bit registry. Switch to compiling as 64-bit instead. (There is a 32-bit registry instead, which can be found buried within the 64-bit hives but you likely want to change the actual 64-bit version).

Comment: How do you define if 64 or 32 compilation

Comment: @ahmad To the left of the green "Local Windows Debugger" button it probably says "x86". Change that to "x64".

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am using Mingw

Comment: @ahmad Do you have the 64 bit version of mingw installed? If not, install it.

Answer (score 2):

> every single one of them returns a zero which means that the function completed without errors but still no values are changed in the registry GUI

The only way that can happen is if either:

1. You are not updating the GUI after making the changes.
2. you are modifying a different area of the Registry then you are viewing, ie if you are modifying the 32bit Registry but viewing the 64bit Registry, or vice versa. Read up about the [Registry Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-redirector), [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys) and [Accessing an Alternate Registry View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/accessing-an-alternate-registry-view) on MSDN for more details about working with the 32bit and 64bit Registry views.

That being said, there are a number of other mistakes in your code.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
HKEY open_reg()
{
    HKEY hKey = NULL;
    int result = RegOpenKeyExA( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                             "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",
                             0,
                             KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_SET_VALUE /* | KEY_WOW64_(32|64)KEY if needed */,
                             &hKey );

    if ( result != 0 )
    {
        cout << " Failed to open Registry, Error " << result << endl;
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Opened Registry key" << endl;
        return hKey;
    }
}

void query_reg_value(HKEY handle)
{
    DWORD cbBuffer = TOTALBYTES;
    std::vector<char> buffer(cbBuffer);

    cout << "\nRetrieving the data..." << endl;

    int result = RegQueryValueExA( handle,
                             "SecurityHealth",
                             NULL,
                             NULL,
                             reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(buffer.data()),
                             &cbBuffer );

    if ( result == 0 ) 
    { 
        cout << "Successfully quered: ";
        while (cbBuffer != 0 && buffer[cbBuffer-1] == '\0') --cbBuffer; // ignore null terminator(s)
        cout.write(buffer.data(), cbBuffer);
        cout << endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Failed to query, Error " << result << endl;
    }
}

void set_reg_value(HKEY handle)
{
    std::string file = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";

    int result = RegSetValueExA( handle,
                             "SecurityHealth",
                             0,
                             REG_EXPAND_SZ,
                             reinterpret_cast<LPCBYTE>(file.c_str()),
                             file.size()+1);
    
    if ( result == 0 ) 
    { 
        cout << "Successfully changed value" << endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Failed to change value, Error " << result << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "testing Windows Registry" << endl;
    HKEY hKey = open_reg();
    if (hKey) {
        query_reg_value(hKey);
        set_reg_value(hKey);
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;   
}
```

However, it should be noted that only admin users have write access to HKLM keys by default, most users have read-only access. As such, it is not a good idea to open a key under HKLM for both reading and writing at the time same, unless you know what you are doing. You should open a key for reading only, read from it, and close it. Same for writing.  For instance:

```cpp
HKEY open_reg(bool isWriting)
{
    HKEY hKey = NULL;
    int result = RegOpenKeyExA( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                             "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",
                             0,
                             (isWriting ? KEY_SET_VALUE : KEY_QUERY_VALUE) /* | KEY_WOW64_(32|64)KEY if needed */,
                             &hKey );

    if ( result != 0 )
    {
        cout << " Failed to open Registry, Error " << result << endl;
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Opened registry key" << endl;
        return hKey;
    }
}

void query_reg_value()
{
    HKEY hKey = open_reg(false);
    if (!hKey) return;

    DWORD cbBuffer = TOTALBYTES;
    std::vector<char> buffer(cbBuffer);

    cout << "\nRetrieving the data..." << endl;

    int result = RegQueryValueExA( hKey,
                             "SecurityHealth",
                             NULL,
                             NULL,
                             reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(buffer.data()),
                             &cbBuffer );

    if ( result == 0 ) 
    { 
        cout << "Successfully quered: ";
        while (cbBuffer != 0 && buffer[cbBuffer-1] == '\0') --cbData; // ignore null terminator(s)
        cout.write(buffer.data(), cbBuffer);
        cout << endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Failed to query, Error " << result << endl;
    }

    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}

void set_reg_value()
{
    HKEY hKey = open_reg(true);
    if (!hKey) return;

    std::string file = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";

    int result = RegSetValueExA( hKey,
                             "SecurityHealth",
                             0,
                             REG_EXPAND_SZ,
                             reinterpret_cast<LPCBYTE>(file.c_str()),
                             file.size()+1);
    
    if ( result == 0 ) 
    { 
        cout << "Successfully changed value" << endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Failed to change value, Error " << result << endl;
    }

    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}

int main()
{
    cout << "testing Windows Registry" << endl;
    query_reg_value();
    set_reg_value();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;   
}
```